# Binary search for the position of the element that is just smaller that a value

Tags: c++, search, vector, binary-search-tree

C++ newbie here! Given a sorted vector `v` (with non-unique values) and a scalar `x`, how can one performs a binary search and return the position of the element that is equal or just smaller than `x`.

```
std::vector<double> v { 0.9,0.78,0.6,0.4,0.33,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.07 }
double x = 0.7;

int position = BinaryFindPosition(v.begin(),v.end(),x);
// position is 2
```

Comment: Simple -- use `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound`.

Comment: OP - Look up what the two functions that @PaulMcKenzie referred you to.  Since you said non-unique values, you may want to use `upper_bound`.  Also note that your values are sorted in *reverse* order (largest value first).  You must use the overload that takes a comparator.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps You can use `rbegin()` / `rend()` instead of custom comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::lower_bound`. Note that since your vector is ordered large-to-small, you should use `rbegin()` and `rend()` instead of `begin()` and `end()`:

```
std::vector<double> v { 0.9, 0.78, 0.6, 0.4, 0.33, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.07 };
double x = 0.7;
auto pos = std::distance(std::lower_bound(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), x), v.rend());
cout << pos << endl;
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/QXRFrL)